# Is there way to bind 3-key combination in tmux?

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> combination to switch to move to right pane. I like idea of terminator to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrows to switch between inner terminals, but I also like vim navigation commands

Comment: `L` in vim is moving to Right not Left ;-)

Comment: yes, duplicated, close please.